# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in `node_modules/aws-sdk/lib` using React.JS

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, aws-sdk

I am following [this tutorial](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-use-aws-dynamodb-in-react-70b55ffff93e) for using DynamoDB with React.JS but I get an error that the `aws-sdk` library can't resolve `util`.

It is a node package so I shouldn't actually change its code.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer when using it for `Angular` [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/3501). It also works fine for React.js.

Just install the `util` package: `yarn add util`.

The `aws-sdk` package should have this included in its package file as a dependency.